# How to make statistics; Second: How to write file like this

Tags: c#

First:I have to make a statistics from my csv( https://pastebin.com/jxNSzVYP ) by province. Somewhere you can find a province like this "HU-GD" then you have to see that like "HU" so first 2 letters. And i have to count how many SI/GA/etc province are there. After, i have to write out, when it is at least 3.  (If the csv changes, i mean there will no more HU/SI/ etc, and there will a new one, the program have to count that.) [Check: Describe expected result]

Second: I have to make a new "newCNtunnels.csv" file. When there is a province like this "HU-GD" i have to separete them and write them with same datas, just the province is different. [Check: Describe expected result]

I am not a big programmer, so please do not over complicate this.
Sorry for my English. It is not my first language, but probably you have already noticed this.
Thanks for the help!

I am using windows 10 and visual studio. C# language

```
    struct datas
    {
        public string name;
        public int length;
        public string date;
        public string province;
    }
    datas[] tunnel = new datas[99];


        int i = 0;
        int howmanyrow= 0;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("CNtunnels.csv");
        sr.ReadLine();
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            String[] onerow= sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
            tunnel[i].name= onerow[0];
            tunnel[i].length= Convert.ToInt32(onerow[1]);
            tunnel[i].date= onerow[2];
            tunnel[i].province= onerow[3];
            i++;
            howmanyrow++;

        }
        sr.Close();
```

Excepted results:

https://pastebin.com/EsQz16A0

Answer (score 0):

See following solution :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_CSV_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        const string OUTPUT_CSV_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.csv";
        const string OUTPUT_STATISTICS_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\statistic.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Data data = new Data(INPUT_CSV_FILENAME);
            data.WriteStatistics(OUTPUT_STATISTICS_FILENAME);
            data.WriteCSV(OUTPUT_CSV_FILENAME);
        }
    }
    class Data
    {
        public static List<Data> datas = new List<Data>();
        public string name;
        public int length;
        public string date;
        public string province;

        public Data() { }
        public Data(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string line = "";
            int rowCount = 0;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ';' });
                    if (++rowCount > 1)
                    {
                        string[] splitProvidence = splitArray[3].Split(new char[] { '-' });

                        foreach (string providence in splitProvidence)
                        {
                            Data newRow = new Data();
                            Data.datas.Add(newRow);

                            newRow.name = splitArray[0];
                            newRow.length = int.Parse(splitArray[1]);
                            newRow.date = splitArray[2];
                            newRow.province = providence;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        public void WriteStatistics(string filename)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);

            var groups = datas.GroupBy(x => x.province).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", group.Key, group.Count());
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
        public void WriteCSV(string filename)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
            string header = string.Join(";", new string[] { "name","length","date","province"});
            writer.WriteLine(header);
            foreach (Data data in datas)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(";",new string[] {
                    data.name,
                    data.length.ToString(),
                    data.date,
                    data.province
                }));
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```